# How would one integrates SmartSprites/csssprites into a Play Application?

Tags: playframework

[SmartSprites/csssprites](http://csssprites.org/) is an automatic sprites generator, that is usually run during build.

Since there is no traditional build in a Play app, where would one integrate Smart Sprites instead into the Play app life cycle?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options here

1. Create a PlayPlugin which detects changes to those files and runs the necessary compilation
2. Simply run the compilation at your own will, whenever you decide you need to

Obviously option 1 is the right solution, but not as straight forward. There is a [LESS module](http://www.playframework.org/modules/less) that should point you in the right direction. It does a similar function, so will give you a good starting point!

I think this may get easier in Play2.0, with the introduction of LESS and DART etc.

Comment: Dart is integrated into Play 2.0 ? Google Dart, that was just released a few months ago?

Comment: I believe I read on some of the google groups that it was intended to be in there. Not sure if it is there yet though!

Comment: I'm really looking forward to seeing how Play! looks like in a year. It's really great in present tense, but it's still a bit chaotic/immature (e.g. modules still don't have votes/usage counters, so it's hard to know which modules are really worth looking into, there are still a lot of changes in Play 2.0 (and if you develop on 1.X, you'll either have to migrate or be left behind))

Comment: not convinced you will be left behind if you continue with 1.x. Modules will continue to evolve Play, and Play 1.x may continue to evolve in its own right, but is pretty stable as is.